# ORDER a table from an column which is in another table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

[SQL Fiddle](http://rextester.com/VJD71559) And Here is my whole code:

```
DROP TABLE tmdb_movies;
CREATE TABLE tmdb_movies (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title TEXT NOT NULL,
  popularity INTEGER NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO tmdb_movies (tmdb_id, movie_title, popularity) VALUES
(1, 'Logan', '88.4'),
(2, 'Iron Man', '74.3'),
(3, 'SuperMan', '102.56');

DROP TABLE genres;
CREATE TABLE genres (
  tmdb_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  genres_name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO genres (tmdb_id, genres_name) VALUES
(1, 'Crime'),
(1, 'Comedy'),
(1, 'Drama'),
(2, 'Action'),
(2, 'Horror'),
(2, 'Documentary'),
(3, 'Music');


SELECT distinct genres.tmdb_id

FROM genres

JOIN tmdb_movies USING (tmdb_id)

ORDER BY tmdb_movies.popularity DESC
```

What, i am doing here is: I want to sort table by `popularity` column in `tmdb_movies` table.

The SQL query is working perfectly fine in the `[SQL Fiddle][1]`

But, i am getting this error, when i run it in my MySQL

> ## 3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'DB.tmdb_movies.popularity' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

This is probably because of my default SQL mode. Do i need to change the mode? Anyway to do this, without changing the mode, because i think default mode will be better?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you don't want to add the popularity to the select?

`SELECT distinct genres.tmdb_id, tmdb_movies.popularity
FROM genres
JOIN tmdb_movies USING (tmdb_id)
ORDER BY tmdb_movies.popularity DESC`

Comment: Hey, i heard `distinct` slow down the speed, can i use something else?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the purpose of the query is. The same result would be yielded by simply selecting from the movies table and ordering the result.
`SELECT tmdb_id, 
FROM tmdb_movies
ORDER BY popularity DESC`